# installtion failure when setting up the Ansible Tower in centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, python, ansible, ansible-tower

I am setting up an Ansible Tower in a CentOS 7 machine. I proceed through the installation as per instructions from 
[this document](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-configure-ansible-tower-on-centos-rhel/)

But when I do the installation i get the following error

```
TASK [config_dynamic : Set database to internal or external] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'match'. String: {{ ( (pg_host is not defined or pg_host == '' or pg_host == '127.0.0.1') or (pg_host | match('/.*')) ) | ternary('internal', 'external') }}"}
```

This is when I execute the setup.sh file as per the document to install ansible tower.

I'm trying to install Ansible tower version 3.2.5
My python version is 2.7.5
additionl ansible details are as follows

```
ansible 2.9.1
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Apr  9 2019, 14:30:50) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
```

What is causing this issue? Is this due to postgresql configuration issue ?? I followd the document and it seemed postgresql will get configured via the ansible installtion playbook.

what is causing this ??

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same error message while running an unrelated playbook. I downgraded Ansible to v2.8.7 and it went away. It's either a bug in the latest versions or expected behaviour. I couldn't find any mention of it in the 2.9 changelog:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.9/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.9.rst